# How to get hex string from signed integer

Tags: python

Say I have the classic 4-byte signed integer, and I want something like

```
print hex(-1)
```

to give me something like

> 0xffffffff

In reality, the above gives me `-0x1`. I'm dawdling about in some lower level language, and python commandline is quick n easy.

So.. is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
>>> print(hex (-1 & 0xffffffff))
0xffffffff
```

or, a variant that always returns fixed size (there may well be a better way to do this):

```
>>> def hex3(n):
...     return "0x%s"%("00000000%s"%(hex(n&0xffffffff)[2:-1]))[-8:]
...
>>> print hex3(-1)
0xffffffff
>>> print hex3(17)
0x00000011
```

Or, avoiding the hex() altogether, thanks to Ignacio and bobince:

```
def hex2(n):
    return "0x%x"%(n&0xffffffff)

def hex3(n):
    return "0x%s"%("00000000%x"%(n&0xffffffff))[-8:]
```

Comment: Don't rely on the 'L' suffix, it is going away in Python 3.0 so hex2 will chop off a digit. The %x formatting operator is generally a better bet than hex().

Comment: Incorporated comment and Ignacios option below into accepted answer (and gave Ignacio an upvote)

Comment: Please, replace return "0x%s"%("00000000%s"%(hex(n&0xffffffff)[2:-1]))[-8:] by return "0x%s"%("00000000%s"%(hex(n&0xffffffff)[2:]))[-8:]

Answer (score 4):

Try this function:

```
'%#4x' % (-1 & 0xffffffff)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```py
"0x{:04x}".format((int(my_num) & 0xFFFF), '04x')
```

where `my_num` is the required number.