# Converting a value into 4 byte hex in python

Tags: python, hex

I want to convert any value (that can be negative or positive) into hex. My current method does this.

The read value in this example is 4003.

```
workingline = stringdb.readline().split(";")
print hex(int(workingline[0]))
```

This returns

```
0xfa3
```

It should be:

```
0xa30f0000
```

(Padded with zeros and inverted hexadecimal) IF the value is negative it should be:

```
0xFEFFFFFF
```

With the value -2.

I assume padding does not help in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to get hex string from signed integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228702/how-to-get-hex-string-from-signed-integer)

Answer (score 4):

You want the `struct` module:

```
>>> struct.pack("<I", 4003).encode('hex')
'a30f0000'
```

For -2, you'll need to do some other work:

```
>>> struct.pack("<I", -2 + 2**32).encode('hex')
'feffffff'
```

A way to do it for any value is:

```
struct.pack("<I", (value + 2**32) % 2**32).encode('hex')
```

Comment: This appears to only work for positive values. Do you know another means to make it work for negative values as well?

Comment: Alright, thank you! I suppose I will just make a IF statement for two methods. :)

Comment: Using `"<i"` instead of `"<I"` does the right thing without the `+ 2**32`.