# How to convert int to 4 byte hex

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex

I need to convert an unsigned integer like 4003 to its hex representation. The output of [the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867207/69537)

```
print(struct.pack("<I", 4003).encode('hex'))
```

is

> a30f0000

How can I get the following output?

> 00000fa3

It's not necessary to use `struct.pack`. Any other approach would be appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to convert 4003 to hex, right? I'm asking because I'm not sure how struct.pack works.

Comment: @Ludwik Yes that's what I'm trying to do. I need to convert an unsigned integer to hex.

Comment: @daniel wow, even the same constant

Comment: @Ludwik I just copied the answer from the linked question :)

Comment: Before you proceed any further, I suggest brushing up on the topic of endianness. Your code specifically requested the value to be packed in little-endian order (the `<`). That's why you got that output. You wanted in big-endian order so naturally you should have gone with a different format.

Comment: @JeffMercado You are right, I didn't know `<` is denoting little-endian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> '{:08x}'.format(4003)
'00000fa3'
```

Comment: You should add this link (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to the format language docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired result using

```
print(struct.pack(">I", 4003).encode('hex'))
```