# Python: convert string of multiple hexadecimal values to integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex, decimal, string-conversion

I am having string of four `hex` numbers like:

```
"0x00 0x01 0x13 0x00"
```

which is equivalent to `0x00011300`. How i can convert this hex value to integer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get hex string from signed integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228702/how-to-get-hex-string-from-signed-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are having string of `hex` values. You may remove `' 0x'` from the string to get the single hex number string. For example:

```
my_str =  "0x00 0x01 0x13 0x00"
hex_str = my_str.replace(' 0x', '')
```

where value hold by `hex_str` will be:

```
'0x00011300'   # `hex` string
```

Now you may convert `hex` string to `int` as:

```
>>> int(hex_str, 16)
70400
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s="0x00 0x01 0x13 0x00"
>>> a=0
>>> for b in s.split():
...    a = a*256 + int(b,16)
... 
>>> a
70400
>>> hex(a)
'0x11300'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here [Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python).

**Without** the 0x prefix, you need to specify the base explicitly, otherwise there's no way to tell:

```
x = int("deadbeef", 16)
```

**With** the 0x prefix, Python can distinguish hex and decimal automatically.

```
print int("0xdeadbeef", 0)
3735928559

print int("10", 0)
10
```

(You must specify 0 as the base in order to invoke this prefix-guessing behavior; omitting the second parameter means to assume base-10. See the comments for more details.)